# HTTPS version 1 vs v2 - differences

Tags: ssl, https, tls1.2

What are the major differences between HTTPS `1.x` vs HTTPS `2.x`?
Is the TLS and SSL part came in version `2.x`?

Is HTTP/2 (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP/2) also called HTTPS 2? Is HTTP 1.1 ( https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2068 ) also called HTTPS 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no HTTPS 1.x or HTTPS 2.x. There are only HTTP 1.0, HTTP 1.1 and HTTP/2. HTTPS means only that any of these HTTP protocols are encapsulated inside a TLS connection.

The TLS part is basically the same for all of these. But there are some restrictions regarding the protocol versions, ciphers and TLS compression when using TLS with HTTP/2, see [RFC 7540, section 9.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7540#page-67) for the details. And to make it easier for the server to know the major HTTP protocol version used inside this TLS connection the client should use the ALPN TLS extension to tell the server that it supports HTTP/2.

Comment: Maybe you can add that HTTPS = HTTP over SSL/TLS.

Comment: @LexLi: I think this should be obvious from " HTTPS means only that any of these HTTP protocols are encapsulated inside a TLS connection"

Comment: Brilliant answer. Thanks a lot!! it clears all the confusions.

Comment: actually HTTP/2 does not support SSL, it only supports TLS